# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels): factor X has new levels

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I did a logistic regression:

```
 EW <- glm(everwrk~age_p + r_maritl, data = NH11, family = "binomial")
```

Moreover, I want to predict `everwrk` for each level of `r_maritl`.

`r_maritl` has the following levels:

```
levels(NH11$r_maritl)
 "0 Under 14 years" 
 "1 Married - spouse in household" 
 "2 Married - spouse not in household"
 "3 Married - spouse in household unknown" 
 "4 Widowed"                               
 "5 Divorced"                             
 "6 Separated"                             
 "7 Never married"                        
 "8 Living with partner"  
 "9 Unknown marital status"
```

So I did:

```
predEW <- with(NH11,
expand.grid(r_maritl = c( "0 Under 14 years", "1 Married - 
spouse in household", "2 Married - spouse not in household", "3 Married - 
spouse in household unknown", "4 Widowed", "5 Divorced", "6 Separated", "7 
Never married", "8 Living with partner", "9 Unknown marital status"),
age_p = mean(age_p,na.rm = TRUE)))

cbind(predEW, predict(EW, type = "response",
                        se.fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence",
                        newdata = predEW))
```

The Problem is I get the following response:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
>     object$xlevels) : factor r_maritl has new levels 0 Under 14 years, Married 
>       - spouse in household unknown

Sample Data:

```
str(NH11$age_p)
num [1:33014] 47 18 79 51 43 41 21 20 33 56 ...

str(NH11$everwrk)
Factor w/ 2 levels "2 No","1 Yes": NA NA 2 NA NA NA NA NA 2 2 ...

str(NH11$r_maritl)
Factor w/ 10 levels "0 Under 14 years",..: 6 8 5 7 2 2 8 8 8 2 ...
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data? I cannot reproduce your problem with e.g. `mtcars`. Also, are there unused factors in your dataset `NH11`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr** it looks like you have some levels in your factor that are not represented in your data, that get dropped from the factors used in the model.  In hindsight this isn't terribly surprising, since you won't be able to predict responses for these levels.  That said, it's *mildly* surprising that R doesn't do something nice for you like generate `NA` values automatically.  You can solve this problem by using `levels(droplevels(NH11$r_maritl))` in constructing your prediction frame, or equivalently `EW$xlevels$r_maritl`.

A reproducible example:

```
maritl_levels <- c( "0 Under 14 years", "1 Married - spouse in household", 
  "2 Married - spouse not in household", "3 Married - spouse in household unknown", 
  "4 Widowed", "5 Divorced", "6 Separated", "7 Never married", "8 Living with partner", 
 "9 Unknown marital status")
set.seed(101)
NH11 <- data.frame(everwrk=rbinom(1000,size=1,prob=0.5),
                 age_p=runif(1000,20,50),
                 r_maritl = sample(maritl_levels,size=1000,replace=TRUE))
```

Let's make a missing level:

```
NH11 <- subset(NH11,as.numeric(NH11$r_maritl) != 3)
```

Fit the model:

```
EW <- glm(everwrk~r_maritl+age_p,data=NH11,family=binomial)
predEW <- with(NH11,
  expand.grid(r_maritl=levels(r_maritl),age_p=mean(age_p,na.rm=TRUE)))
predict(EW,newdata=predEW)
```

Success!

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
>        factor r_maritl has new levels 2 Married - spouse not in household

```
predEW <- with(NH11,
           expand.grid(r_maritl=EW$xlevels$r_maritl,age_p=mean(age_p,na.rm=TRUE)))
predict(EW,newdata=predEW)
```

Comment: I really, really doubt it [version differences]. This is all core R functionality that's been around for decades and exercised by thousands of users. My prior is very strongly on a subtle typo by the OP.

Comment: Cool, I learned something today. (I don't *think* I had encountered this particular problem before.)

Comment: that command doesn't do what you think it does.  Use `droplevels()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer, I was also facing the same problem of new levels.
I made below changes in my code.

1. I was using `data.frame()` and replace it by `expand.grid()` function
2. Added `na.rm=TRUE` along with the variable in mean function
3. Replaced factor(1:2) by `glmoutput$xlevels$variablename`

and the solution works!